# Enforce structure on outgoing data in DRF serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In my particular case, I would like to enforce the length of the given iterable for a ListSerializer. I did the following, it works. However, is it the right place to intercept the data? How can I intercept at the earliest stage?

```
class CustomListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        count = kwargs.pop('count', None)
        self.count = count
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def to_representation(self, data):
        if self.count is not None:
            if len(data) != self.count:
                raise serializers.ValidationError("Incorrect list size")
```

Please note that the `validate` method is for incoming-data (JSON/serialized to native type), I am looking for enforcing the structure of the outgoing (serialized) data so as to comply with the API specification.

Comment: No, validation should not take place inside `to_representation`; it should be in validation methods as shown in [the docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation).

Comment: I tried that, using `validate` method. But that method was not called. I have updated the questions.

Comment: Well in fact it's not really clear what you are trying to do here. Validation is for *incoming* data; you verify that the data posted to your serializer is valid to be saved into the database. So I'm not sure why you want to validate data on *output*; when would it ever not be valid? And what is `self.count` actually for?

Comment: I want to ensure that in the API response (JSON) the size of the list is as specified in the count.

Comment: I have rephrased the question to make the outgoing data part explicit.